# Narrowing a selection based on values in a Map<String,String>

Tags: apex, soql, bulkification, method

Each day, I want to...

1. Upsert new/changed time logs via Apex.
2. Generate a Map where key = Jira_Issue_c, value = Activity__c
3. Find previously created records matching Jira_Issue_c but not Activity__c
4. Set Activity__c to the latest value from the map.

```
List<Time_Log__c> timeLogs = new List<Time_Log__c>();
Time_Log__c timeLog = new Time_Log__c(Jira_Issue__c='CAR-1', Activity='Enhancement', Time_Log_Id__c=42);
timeLogs.add(timeLog);
Time_Log__c timeLog = new Time_Log__c(Jira_Issue__c='CAR-2', Activity='Defect', Time_Log_Id__c=43);
timeLogs.add(timeLog);
upsert timeLogs Time_Log_Id__c;

Map<String,String> mapIssueToActivity = new Map<String,String>();
for (Time_Log__c timeLog; timeLogs) {
  mapIssueToActivity.put(timeLog.Jira_Issue__c, timeLog.Activity__c);
}

List<Time_Log__c> timeLogsToFix = [SELECT Jira_Issue__c, Activity__c FROM Time_Log__c WHERE Id NOT IN :timeLogs];
for (Time_Log__c timeLogToFix; timeLogsToFix) {
  String latestActivity = (String)
mapIssueToActivity.get(timeLogToFix.Jira_Issue__c);
  if (timeLogToFix.Activity__c != latestActivity) {
    timeLogToFix.Activity__c = latestActivity;
  }
}
update timeLogsToFix;
```

Want to get a smaller List of records to update where their Jira Issue / Activity do not have a pair in the Map. Is there a better approach than to iterate through all records I did not just upload (as I am doing above)?

Comment: It's hard to follow your textual description. Could you post the relevant portion of the code you're trying to bulkify

Comment: you can add JIRA keyset to query - Jira_Issue__c IN <relevant_jira> and NOT IN <recentlyUpdatedLogs>. order by last modified asc (older ones)